A/C line set flashing
The flashing for my a/c line set has a gap inside where mice and critters can come in. Is it safe to use a spray foam to seal this gap between inside of flashing and a/c line set? Will it compress a/c lines or damage them in any way?

There should be no issues with the foam collapsing the lines.  There may be an issue if the lines ever need to be replaced, but that still can be overcome.
Without a pic of the area to know of any other details, the use of foam is probably your best bet.  Expanding foam has been used in my area often for the purpose of closing gaps to the outside.
Use something like mouse shield, or something equivalent.

Thank you for your input

With mice OP might want metal screening/steel wool inside of the foam.

@crip,  fixed that.

Ok thank you. No current mice issues in my unit, or in surrounding units. Just want to be preventative. My main concern is if the spray foam would hinder or damage the a/c lines in any way.
